# Spring Boot and GraalVM native-image

Tags: java, spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

With the latest releases of Spring Boot `2.3.0`, spring-graalvm-native `0.7.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`, GraalVM `20.1.0.r11` and the corresponding blog posts

- https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/16/spring-tips-the-graalvm-native-image-builder-feature
- https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2020/05/spring-boot-graalvm

I also started to play around with one of my apps.

Luckily I was able to compile my app without any big hurdles. My `compile.sh` script looks as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "[-->] Detect artifactId from pom.xml"
ARTIFACT=$(mvn -q \
-Dexec.executable=echo \
-Dexec.args='${project.artifactId}' \
--non-recursive \
exec:exec);
echo "artifactId is '$ARTIFACT'"

echo "[-->] Detect artifact version from pom.xml"
VERSION=$(mvn -q \
  -Dexec.executable=echo \
  -Dexec.args='${project.version}' \
  --non-recursive \
  exec:exec);
echo "artifact version is '$VERSION'"

echo "[-->] Detect Spring Boot Main class ('start-class') from pom.xml"
MAINCLASS=$(mvn -q \
-Dexec.executable=echo \
-Dexec.args='${start-class}' \
--non-recursive \
exec:exec);
echo "Spring Boot Main class ('start-class') is '$MAINCLASS'"

GREEN='\033[0;32m'
RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m'

echo "[-->] Cleaning target directory & creating new one"
rm -rf target
mkdir -p target/native-image

echo "Packaging $ARTIFACT with Maven"
mvn -ntp package > target/native-image/output.txt

echo "[-->] Expanding the Spring Boot fat jar"
JAR="$ARTIFACT-$VERSION.jar"
rm -f $ARTIFACT
echo "Unpacking $JAR"
cd target/native-image
jar -xvf ../$JAR >/dev/null 2>&1
cp -R META-INF BOOT-INF/classes

LIBPATH=`find BOOT-INF/lib | tr '\n' ':'`
CP=BOOT-INF/classes:$LIBPATH

GRAALVM_VERSION=`native-image --version`
echo "Compiling $ARTIFACT with $GRAALVM_VERSION"
{ time native-image \
  --verbose \
  --no-server \
  --no-fallback \
  --enable-all-security-services \
  -H:Name=$ARTIFACT \
  -Dspring.native.remove-unused-autoconfig=true \
  -Dspring.native.remove-yaml-support=true \
  -Dspring.native.remove-xml-support=true \
  -Dspring.native.remove-spel-support=true \
  -Dspring.native.remove-jmx-support=true \
  -cp $CP $MAINCLASS >> output.txt ; } 2>> output.txt

if [[ -f $ARTIFACT ]]
then
  printf "${GREEN}SUCCESS${NC}\n"
  mv ./$ARTIFACT ..
  exit 0
else
  cat output.txt
  printf "${RED}FAILURE${NC}: an error occurred when compiling the native-image.\n"
  exit 1
fi
```

But now my troubles start: My app relies on some CSVs during startup to load data. 
The data is loaded like this

```
InputStream is = CSVUtil.class.getResourceAsStream("/myData.csv");
```

The file is present at `/src/main/resources/myData.csv`

As said the compilation works without an issue but once I start the app it can't find the CSV.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:167) ~[na:na]
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:113) ~[na:na]
    at ch.aaap.raw.CSVUtil.getData(CSVUtil.java:33) ~[na:na]
...
```

It seems that it's not part of the compilation. Any hints how I can make the `native-image` command aware about the fact that I need these CSVs?

Comment: Yeah GraalVM Native Image compilation needs to know about resource files, since they must be baked into the resulting native executable also. But it seems you already found the correct configuration flag with `-H:IncludeResources` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like adding following argument helps
`-H:IncludeResources='.*/*.csv$'`